# Prevent resolve.conf from being overriden

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, dns

I have problems with my VPN setup. I have the Cisco AnyConnect client installed, as well as the openconnect network plugin for the network-manager. Both have a fundamental problem:

1. Cisco's AnyConnect

   Works fine, until after a while I get disconnected not only from the VPN, but from my whole network. I cannot connect to the Internet anymore, even with VPN turned off. `sudo service network-manager restart` does not help, eventually I have to reboot.
2. openconnect

   Does not resolve domains outside of my VPN provider. The difference between the modified `resolve.conf` here is that openconnect does not add additional IP adresses pointing to DNS resolver.

Currently, I use openconnect and overwrite the `resolve.conf` with the one that would have been created through Cisco's AnyConnect client. Any idea how to automate this or even fix it?

```
# resolve.conf by AnyConnect
domain my.vpn-provider.com
nameserver <IP>
nameserver <IP>
search my.vpn-provider.com WAG160N


# resolve.conf by openconnect
domain my.vpn-provider.com
search my.vpn-provider.com WAG160N
```

I am on Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `/etc/resolv.conf` however you want and then set it immutable with
 `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf`. I would suggest adding a note to the file indicating that you have set it immutable before you set it immutable, to prevent future confusion.

Comment: Doing this prevents the client from connecting. Ubuntu 18.04, AnyConnect v 4.3.05017.

Comment: Sadly the client doesn't connect anymore... If only it was open source.

Comment: 9 years later, and this is still the best answer....?  Way to go, Cisco.